# Remove a character from a string in list

Tags: python, string, list

How i can remove the \t from last string in this list?

`['1', 'name', 'family', '43\n'] --> ['1', 'name', 'family', '43']`

Comment: there is no `\t` in this list ... but presumably you should do this at the point where you turn a string into this list

Comment: Thankful. What code should I put where I convert the string to a list?

Comment: you would have to show us how you are making this into a list ... presumably just something like changing `sublist = line.split(",")` to `sublist = line.strip().split(",")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map` and `strip`,

```
In [1]: l = ['1', 'name', 'family', '43\n']

In [2]: list(map(str.strip, l))
Out[2]: ['1', 'name', 'family', '43']
```